# Projecting Sphere to Rectangle/Square using Mercerator Projection

Tags: algorithm, map-projections

I am learning some projection technique where we can project a 3d object like globe to a 2d. I have the 3d coordinates of points on the surface of sphere same as globe. Here is a reference where a globe can be projected on a plane using Stereo-graphic projection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) but this projection project the globe to a circle but i am trying to project sphere to a rectangle the same way as the globe is projected on a small paper (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Answer (score 0):

For any projection, you're going to need to construct a map (no pun intended) from one coordinate system to the other.

For the mercator projection, the map can be a function of your sphere coordinate (azimuth & elevation) to rectangular coordinate (x & y).

Azimuth is your x coordinate. Elevation is your y coordinate.

Comment: How can you say that Azimuth is your x coordinate. Elevation is your y coordinate, could you provide me some sources or sites from where you have considered this point ?

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia page you linked shows that the latitude and longitude lines are straight. So your xy-coordinates must be lat/long. And lay/long are just proxies for elevation/azimuth.